Expected value of number of local maxima of numbers randomly placed on a circle
So I just came across this question and can find nothing like it online.
Suppose you have the numbers $1- 18$ and you randomly distribute them around a circle. What is the expected number of numbers that are greater than both numbers next to them? For example, if you had the sequence $. . . 3 6 4 . . . $, $6$ fulfills the condition but $3$ and $4$ cannot.
You need to do each number individually. I thought for any number $i$ the probability is $1/3$ as it needs to be greater than both of them. However, I think this is wrong. The probability it is greater than any one of its neighbors is obviously $1/2$, but the condition of being greater than one of the neighbors changes the condition of being greater than the second one I assume.
If I found this, then the expected value would just be $18$ times this number. Does anyone have ideas for this? Thanks

The probability of fulfilling the criterion is not the same for every number. In the extreme cases $18$ fulfils the criterion with probability $1$ and $1$ fulfils it with probabilty $0$.

Don't do it for each number, but do it for each space. That's the idea (indicator variable) that I think you're going for.

Re Will's answer, see Linearity of Expectation,
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not
independent of each other.

A related problem: What is the expected no. of local maxima in a circular permutation of $n$ numbers?

By linearity of the expected value it is indeed $18$ times the probability that a number at a given position is greater than its neighbours.
By symmetry that probability is $1/3$.
So the answer is $18/3=6$.

Could you expand on the ‘By symmetry…’?  (I can see that the probability is ⅓, by considering that there are 6 equally-likely ways of arranging any three different numbers, and 2 of those 6 put the largest in the middle.  But I suspect you have a more elegant approach…?)

$X$ is either the largest, in the middle or the lowest among three distinct numbers $X$, $Y$, $Z$. By symmetry those three possibilities happen with the same probability, hence $1/3$.
I don't know if that's more elegant than what you wrote, maybe yes if you consider the fewer calculation, the more elegant :)
